# Algorithm for plotting handwritten texts

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a handwritten text as an image file and I want to recreate it using a pen plotter. I need to detect where the line starts and where it moves. Is there any algorithm to do this?

My idea is to find the end of the line that are thicker and then just trace where the line goes and when there's an overlapping lines it will go the line with the smallest angle.

Comment: Just to show how far the current algorithms are: https://www.digitaltrends.com/cool-tech/handwriting-replication-algorithm/

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. Perhaps you don't understand English quiet well. I did NOT mention anything about handwriting replication. Never. What I want is to do is to find out where each line starts and where it goes so I can 'print' a handwritten text and make it look like it actually is handwritten, and not printed.